# Unable to handle Chrome alert with C# NUnit WebDriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

We have recently started writing test to be executed in Chrome but we are experiencing problems handling browser generated alerts that were easily dealt with in Internet Explorer using:

`var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.UnexpectedAlertBehavior = "Accept"`

Is there a ChromeOptions equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem whereby my **C#** tests throws this error -  "OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure?}" each time there were browser-generated alerts and the tests die immediately the alert is generated.

In my tests, the alerts are generated when I try to delete or edit some values in my test application. So, I resolved this by writing this piece of code to **accept** the alert;

```
public void ClickAcceptOnJsAlert()
{
    var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    if (js != null)
    {
        js.ExecuteScript("window.alert = function(){}");
        js.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
    }

}
```

And this piece of code to reject the alert;

```
public void ClickDismissOnJsAlert()
{
    var js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    if (js != null)
    {
        js.ExecuteScript("window.alert = function(){}");
        js.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(){return false;}");
    }

}
```

However, to use this piece of code, one will need to anticipate the alert by doing;

For example, if clicking on a particular element generates the alert, I did this to accept alert;

```
ClickAcceptOnJsAlert();
element.Click();
```

or the following to get rid of the alert;

```
ClickDismissOnJsAlert();
element.Click()
```

This is what I did to work around the problem, I hope it works for you as well.